# Set Meteor Reconnect Time

Tags: javascript, meteor

A client of my meteor app attempts to reconnect to the server in increasing time intervals. Using `((Meteor.status().retryTime - (new Date()).getTime())/1000).toFixed(0)`, I have roughly estimated that the reconnect intervals are 1st: 1 second , 2nd: 2 seconds, 3rd: 4 seconds , 4th: 12 seconds, 5th: 18 seconds, 6th: 62 seconds, 7th: 108 seconds. Is there a way to set the interval length? For example, could I set the reconnect interval to 5 seconds every time no matter how many times I have already tried to reconnect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

**UPDATE**:
I built a package to achieve this functionally - [nspangler:autoreconnect](https://github.com/nspangler/autoreconnect)

---

My final solution was to track the `Meteor.status()` and build a custom interval when the status was `waiting`. This is code on the client.

```
 // Variable For Storing Interval ID
 var intervalId = null;

 Meteor.startup( function () {

  // Interval Reconnect
  Tracker.autorun( function () {
    // Start Pinging For Recconect On Interval, only if status is faiting and intervalId is null
    if(Meteor.status().status === "waiting" && intervalId === null) {
        intervalId = Meteor.setInterval( function () {
            console.log("attempt to reconnect");
            Meteor.reconnect()
        }, 1000);
        console.log(intervalId);
    }
    // Stop Trying to Reconnect If Connected, and clear Interval
    if(Meteor.status().status === "connected" && intervalId != null) {
        console.log("cleared interval");
        Meteor.clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the retryTime to one day from the time the app get disconnected from the server with Meteor.disconnect? I have tried Meteor.disconnect();
Meteor.status().retryTime = 86400000; This seems to work, however, sometimes the app regains connection (meteor tries to re-establish a connection and succeeds). Another observation is that Meteor tries to reconnect after calling Meteor.disconnect. If this is the case, what is the purpose of Meteor.disconnect if it always tries to connect and most of the time (without setting retryTime) it succeeds?

Comment: @Neutrino Remember that Meteor has its own reconnect interval. The solution above is creating an additional reconnect sequence. I assume that when the app connects outside of the above loop is because of the internal meteor connect interval. Read the top question. It explains the exponential growth of the default meteor connect time.